# Migrating dependent entities

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to custom-migrate D7 to D8 articles with references to file(images), taxonomy terms, and users(uid). Do i have to migrate the whole group all these entities belong to with

```
drush migrate_import --group=mygroup
```

to keep the references all right?

Or is it somehow possible to run one subsidiary migration and still keep the references, i mean

```
drush migrate_import mymigration
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The --execute-dependencies option will cause all the migrations your "main" migration depends on to run first, so all references are resolved:

```
drush mi --execute-dependencies mymigration
```

Of course, 'mymigration' needs to reference the migrations it depends on in migration_dependencies:

```
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - my_file_migration
    - my_user_migration
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have additional questions as mine dependencies still dont work:

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have additional questions as mine dependencies still dont work:

* should i run `drush mi` with `--group=mygroup` or better without a group specification with `my_main_migration' only?

* i have 3 migrations: user (works even with picture), file (images, they got imported but not related to the node), and node migration which is the main one that depends on user and file migrations. While users and files are migrated ok into D* instance, nodes are imported but withour references to uid and fid of the child migrations, although i have specified: (see next comments)

Comment: Here is my code:

    'field_logo/target_id':
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: luxus_files
      no_stub: true
      source: fid

    uid:
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: luxus_user
      source: uid
      no_stub: true

    migration_dependencies:
     required:
      - luxus_user
      - luxus_files

Comment: process plugin 'iterator' solved the trouble, it diggs 'fid' out of image fields like a breeze

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done a D7 to D8 migration, but for a migration to D8 from an sql source, I find it's best to do a "child" migration before its "parent. So do the users, terms, and files before migrating the articles. And then if you roll back, do that in the reverse order: parents before children.

This blog post was helpful to me: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/migrating-content-references-drupal-8

This is the way I organize things in my migrations...

In the child migration:

```
process:
  parent_id:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: parent_migration
    source: my_parent_id
```

In the parent migration:

```
process:
# for the label field and any other non-reference fields, create 'stub' values in this manner:
  label_field:
  -
    plugin: get
    source: my_label_field
  -
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'Stub Label'
child_items:
  plugin: migration_lookup
  migration: child_migration
  source: my_child_items
```

Note: if some of your parent entities don't have any child items, you can use the skip_on_empty process plugin as follows to make sure those parent entities are still migrated properly. (If child items are required for all parent entities, you can omit from the migration any parent entities with missing children by changing the 'method' from 'process' to 'row'.)

```
  child_items:
  -
    plugin: skip_on_empty
    method: process
    source: my_child_items
  -
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: child_migration
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. btw what is the `parent_id:` section about? do i have to mention the parent field in the child migration yml file?

Comment: Sorry to have caused confusion; in your case (users, terms, and files), the parent_id doesn't make sense. It depends on what you're migrating. An example in which "parent_id" would make sense is the migration of taxonomy terms and vocabularies: the terms would need to reference the "parent" vocabulary, using "vid" as the parent/vocabulary id.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are automatically processed by their migration_dependencies:

e.g.

```
id: upgrade_d7_field_instance_widget_settings
[...]
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - upgrade_d7_field_instance
  optional:
    - upgrade_d7_field
    - upgrade_d7_field_instance
```

So if you're running all migrations (or all from a tag or group), their migration order is calculated based on their migration_dependencies.

In this example, upgrade_d7_field_instance_widget_settings will only run after upgrade_d7_field_instance has been migrated!
As upgrade_d7_field is a migration_dependency of upgrade_d7_field_instance the order will be:

1. upgrade_d7_field_instance
2. upgrade_d7_field
3. upgrade_d7_field_instance_widget_settings

So you should be careful when running single migrations!

If you're for example running upgrade_d7_user before upgrade_d7_field_instance, your custom user fields values might not be migrated!

This is quite tricky!

I think this might be interesting for you with more details: https://understanddrupal.com/lessons/introduction-migration-dependencies-drupal/